# How to get values of exponential functions in java and how to code the exponential functions

Tags: java, math, exponential

I want to get value of an exponential function to my code, but I don't know how to code to exponential functions in Java. What is the way to code exponential functions in Java?

```
public class Demo {

    // inputs are declared
    private int x[] = {1, 0, 1, 0};
    //weights are declared
    private double w[] = {0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8};
    private double temp = 0;

    private double z = 0;
    private int desiredOutput[] = {0, 1, 1, 1};

    private double sigmoidOutput[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};

    public void calculate() {
        for(int i =0; i < 4; i++) {
            temp = x[i] * w[i];
            z += temp;
        }
        /*
             I want to get the value of 1/(1+e to the power (-z) )
         */
    }

}
```

Comment: We can't do your homework for you. What you can do is show us what you have written so far, and what your understanding is. Then we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I asked this as I really don't know how to code exponential values in java. Here is my code

Comment: Try this : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_exp.htm

Comment: Thanks, this site is also about it: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_exp.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you code should have this after whatever you have written in your calculate method.

Return the result from the calculate method or set result globally or however way you want to use it.

```
  double d = 1+ Math.exp(-z);
  double result = 1/d;
```

Comment: Thanksyou, I also found the answer on the above link

Comment: Can you please accept the answer so that it helps future readers.

Answer (score 0):

As according to the way mentioned here [Math Exponential](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_exp.htm)

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Demo {
        // inputs are declared
        private int x[]={1,0,1,0};
        //weights are declared
        private double w[]={0.4,0.6,0.7,0.8};
        private double temp=0;

        private double z=0;
        private int desiredOutput[]={0,1,1,1};

        private double sigmoidOutput[]={1,1,1,1};

        public void calculate(){
            for(int i =0; i<4; i++){
                temp=x[i]*w[i];
                z+=temp;
            }
            /*
             * I want to get the value of 1/(1+e to the power (-z) )
             */
            double value=(1/(1+Math.exp(-z));
        }
}
```